# Is “the artist rented where he could work" grammatical?

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses, direct-objects

I read a grammar textbook, which says the following is wrong,

> the artist rented where he could work.

And that the correct sentence should be

> the artist rented an apartment where he could work.

But I think both "the artist rented where he could work" and "the artist rented  an apartment where he could work" are right.
Am I right?

Comment: I don't see this as proofreading, the op has identified a particular point of concern: is the word "an apartment" required in that sentence.

Comment: This is not proofreading, which is  the act of checking a draft in order to find and correct errors. This question is asking for clarification about an already-completed document, and specifically about a grammatical aspect.

Comment: @Eden0516 once the problem has been clearly identified, the request is not about proofreading. It's about meaning, grammar and word order. I will say though that the OP's title *appears* to be a proofreading request.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, agreed on the problematic title. A clearer, and slightly shorter alternative might be, ' Is my grammar text correct to criticize, "The artist rented where he could work" ' That said, anyone searching is just as likely to get a hit hit on a question's body text as it's title, so the even shorter, "Is my grammar textbook correct?" would probably suffice (although no doubt it will fall foul of some "How to write a good title" rules).

Comment: However, the present title is more descriptive than the ones you suggested. Good titles help users decide which questions to read or post answers. And prevent the TL;DR crowd from closing it for being off-topic.

Comment: The grammar book actually says that? In speech, it's fine and could arise. In writing, it ain't great.

Comment: You're looking for an intransitive sense for the verb "to rent". There is nothing wrong the the sentence.

Comment: Is "Is x grammatical?" grammatically correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The form without "an apartment" is probably grammatical, but it would be very poorly phrased.

The clause "where he could work" could be a content clause (ie a noun clause) and function as the object of the verb "rent".  But it would mean something like "all the places in which he could work". That's not what you intend.  Instead you want to use that clause as a relative clause to describe the thing that he is actually renting: an apartment.

Using "where ..." also creates a garden path sentence, as you might expect it to continue "The artist rented where he could have bought because he wanted the flexibility"  That "where" means something like "... in a situation in which...".

So, while I don't see your sentence as "ungrammatical" I am sure that you shouldn't use it.

Comment: I read the "rented where he could work" as renting in the area in which it was possible for him to work (vs., say, renting across town where the rent may be lower but the work space was less convenient). ... perhaps renting an apartment near several large mural sites, or near a good source of some esoteric material used in their art.

Comment: But there would be no harm in using it in conversation - would there?  I would say that, speaking in a loosely informal register, it is perfectly natural and hence "correct".

Comment: @WS2 nothing is a problem in conversation, as long as you're prepared to be misunderstood :)

Comment: @sehe I have no difficulty understanding "The artist rented where he could work." as meaning that the artist chose a location to rent property in one of the areas where it was possible for them to work.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Precisely, even more general "The artist would rent places in areas where it possible for them to work". Since according to the question something else was intended, the person using this phrasing will have to anticipate misunderstandings of this kind (or choose to be less ambiguous).

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, there is nothing grammatically wrong with:

> The artist rented where he could work.

But it is a little ambiguous in that it could mean that the artist sub-leased a part of his workplace; or that he had a rental business on the side, and he would operate that from wherever he was doing his main art job. I doubt anyone would actually interpret it in those ways, but the fact that they *could* can create cognitive dissonance and make understanding just a wee bit more difficult.

By contrast:

> The artist rented an apartment where he could work.

is much clearer. (Strictly speaking, I suppose it could be argued that a tiny residual ambiguity remains, but it is barely noticeable and it would only slow down pedants and people on ell.stackexchange.com )

Overall, I think your textbook is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use of where is confusing here.

> The artist rented where he could work.

On other hand, a slightly different sentence with the use of "what" appears perfect.

> The artist rented what he found suitable.

So the meaning "where" conveys in your sentence appears primary problem.

Comment: Shouldn't your introduction (the PS) be included in your profile? Why are you including it in your answer?

Comment: @Eden0516 you are right. removed.

Comment: Perhaps you can consider moving it into your profile?

Comment: will consider that. I had edited the answer but I see your edits as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think I’d call “The artist rented where he could work,” an ungrammatical sentence.  I can think of parallel sentences that sound fine to me.  For example, “The artist remembered where he came from.”

However, “The artist rented where he could work,” doesn’t sound right to me.  (I’m American.)  I would say something like, “... rented a space where he could work,” instead.  I honestly do not know why that is.